# How to call different functions using an argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have come up with the following solution for calling different functions based on an argument value. Is there a better/simpler way?

```
function mainFunction(input, category) {
  categories = {
    'category1': () => { return { /* return stuff */ }}
    'category2': () => { return { /* return stuff */ }}
  }
  return categories[category].call();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason that `category1` and `category2` are _inside_ `mainFunction`, other than to call them based on those string values? Would it make sense in the context of your program if those functions were defined outside of `mainFunction`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's in a module so the mainFunction gets exported. Also, just to avoid passing the input arg for each function individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do directly `categories[category]()`.

However, here is how I would do it, to avoid defining the categories object every time you call this function:

```js
const actions = {
  category1: (a, b, c) => { console.log(a, b, c) },
  category2: () => { return { /* return stuff */ }},
  call: (category, ...args) => {
    if (!actions[category]) {
      throw new Error("Invalid category.")
    }
    return actions[category](...args);
  }
}

actions.call("category1", 42, 7, 0)
```

Comment: I like it. The input arg could be handled like `actions.call('category1', 'some input')`

Comment: @Alan Exactly :-) If you want to use the spread operator, that will be even fancier. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```js
function mainFunction(input, category) {
  const categories = {
    'category1': () => {  
      console.log('cat 1'); 
     },
    'category2': () => { 
      console.log('cat 1'); 
     }
  };
  
  if (categories[category]) {
   return categories[category]();
  } else {
    // throw error here
  }
 
}

mainFunction('test', 'category2');
```